# Android ExpandableListView height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview

I have added an `ExpandableListView` to a `LinearLayout` in an Activity. On the emulator, it shows up as being scrollable and the height is only as big the first item (parent). I've set scrollable to false, but I don't know how to set the height to be as big as the collection of items in the `ExpandableListView`. It must also grow if a parent is expanded. If it's too big, the `LinearLayout` can be scrollable to view the other items.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: can you present same code so we could help thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a custom layout for your listView in xml. It can be a textview or a more complex layout and that both for parent and children. You can use inflated views. In that layout you can set up the height.

I am not quite sure about your question:
 *If it's too big, the linearlayout can be scrollable to view the other items.*
->>>so why do you want to put scrollable to false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It led me onto the LayoutParams of the view. To clear up the ambiguity, I meant that I don't want the ExpandableListView to be scrollable, but the linearlayout that contains it can be.